# Restore database - Operating system error 5(Access is denied.) on Linux

Tags: sql-server, restore, linux, sql-server-2017

I try to restore SQL Server 2017 Express database using **sqlcmd** tool on Ubuntu 16 Server.

My SQL command is:

`RESTORE DATABASE [xxxxx] FROM DISK = N'/home/xxxxxx/DBBackups/xxxx.bak' WITH NORECOVERY, MOVE 'xxxx_Data' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/xxxxx.mdf', MOVE 'xxxx_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/xxxx_log.ldf'`

Error message is:

**BackupDiskFile::OpenMedia: Backup device '/home/xxxxxx/DBBackups/xxxxxxxx.bak' failed to open. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).**

Using `WITH MOVE` option described in this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53153/171620) does not work.

**UPDATE**

Here's another [post](https://medium.com/@amalrikmaia/how-to-restore-a-sql-server-database-on-ubuntu-437882a134bf) and still Access denied error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error indicates `mssql` doesn't have permissions to read the backup file. You can give other users (users other than the file's existing owner or group) read access to the backup file with the `chmod` example below. This will allow the `mssql` daemon user to read the backup file for the restore.

```
sudo chmod o+r /home/xxxx/DBBackups/xxxx.bak
```

Regarding your comment:

> I don't know why Microsoft did not give mssql permissions to access
>   all files

The `mssql` user isn't granted more permissions than it needs during the install, following the security principle of least privilege. Consequently, it won't have permissions to your home directory by default.